# Application insight alerts with notification configurable for email recipient and email body?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm creating an alert on AI. This is the message I received when the alert is triggered. how to make the email body configurable or make and specific message?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to customize the email template for Azure alerts. As a workaround, you can configure a webhook by creating a custom payload so that you can process the alert signal with your custom code

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log-webhook